# Appending to end of a line using 'sed'

Tags: sed

I have a line that says...

```
Fred Flintstone, Bedrock USA
```

and I want it to look like...

```
Fred Flintstone, Bedrock USA ***
```

How do I append a few * to the end of the line using `sed` command?

Answer (score 49):

You can use this:

```
sed 's/$/ ***/' filename
```

If you want to search for a specific string before appending to a line (that is you don't want it appended to EVERY line like the above command) you can use the following, this finds `Fred Flintstone` anywhere in a line, put`^` in front if you only want to match the beginning of the line.

```
sed '/Fred Flintstone/ s/$/ ***/' filename
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  How do you use it to append to a certain line?  The above command does it for every line in the text file.  I'm interested in making in work for all lines that start with the name "Fred"

Comment: @Justin: `sed 's/^Fred.*/& ***/' filename`

Comment: @heemayl: "The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched" -- from `man bash`